# SharePoint item.File - ServerObjectNullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm attempting to load information about all File Items in a list. In this snippet, `item` refers to a  `ListItem`

```
switch(item.FileSystemObjectType)
            {
                case FileSystemObjectType.File:
                    if (ListOptions.IndexFileItems)
                    {
                        ClientContext.Load(item, i => i.File);
                        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        if (item.File.Exists)
```

When the code is run, it reaches the final line and then throws ServerObjectNullReferenceException.

I do not understand this, as the item has declared itself to be of Type `File` in it's `FileSystemObjectType`, should I not expect the `File`property to have a reference, having loaded it? Am I loading the file incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListItem.File is used in document library, please make sure list object is a library:

[ListItem.File property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee538936(v%3Doffice.15))

I tested the code snippet below, work as expected:

```
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev/");
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("dccc");
            CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);
            ctx.Load(items);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem item in items)
            {

                switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
                {
                    case FileSystemObjectType.File:
                        ctx.Load(item, i => i.File);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                        if (item.File.Exists)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.File.Name);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

[image]

So the files are two jpg file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I assume I need to check list.BaseTemplate as talked about [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90418/how-to-check-if-listtemplatetype-enum-is-list-or-library). I'm wondering now if sub-lists can have different types to their parents as my CamlQuery is recursive.